# Delphi Android Pie Chart

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I want to create a pie chart for android (fmx). I researched in google, but no components free. I am looking for the free component or any sample about it.

Are there any sample about pie chart for android ?

Comment: FireMonkey is a cross-platform 2D/3D environment, any FMX chart drawing code should work (no android tag required)...

Comment: Questions asking us to find or recommend a tool, book, tutorial, library, software, or other off-site resource are off topic here. Google or Bing can search for components for you and return links to the results. Good luck.

Comment: `TChart` is included in Delphi and supports the Android platform through the firemonkey framework. For a sample, just drop a `TChart` component on your form and in a button event handler add code like:`with Chart1.AddSeries(TPieSeries.Create(Self)) do
  begin
    AddXY(1, 5, 'TChart');
    AddXY(1, 10, 'Sample');
  end;`.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from drawing it yourself: [`TCanvas.FillArc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.FillArc).

Comment: delphi's charts are very bad graphically. I need modern charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delphi comes with limited TeeChart Lite component suite which does support what you need.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/FireMonkey_and_TeeChart

Check the TChart component and how to use it. It supports both VCL and FMX platform.